# Speedtest Upload speed faster than download AND faster than "actual" through WRT54G VPN router

Tags: router, vpn, speedtest

[Live in Qatar - before people start asking WHY?]

I have a DSL router connected to the internet.
Speedtest when connected directly to the router shows approx 4mbps/0.5mbps which is what I would expect.

I then have a Linksys WRT54G VPN router connected to this.
Speedtest shows approx 2mbps/4mpbs???

I can understand the 2mbps, makes sense that download over VPN (in London) is slower than direct...but I don't understand the 4mbps that upload is showing?

Can anyone shed any light on this?
Thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably this is due to VPN compression enabled. Test file downloaded from Speedtest is already compressed and not affecting result, while file sent to upload test compressed better and trips faster to your VPN server in London.

Comment: Would compression take it from 512kbps up to 4mbps?  Sounds like a huge leap?